# Integral with variable changes

Tags: definite-integrals, stochastic-calculus

if we have

$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}_{I_r}(s)&=\mathbb{E}_{\Phi,\{{g_i}\}}\bigg[\prod\limits_{i\in\Phi}\mathbb{E}_{g_i}(\mathrm{exp}[-sg_iR_i^{-\alpha}]) \bigg]\\
&=\mathbb{E}_{\Phi}\bigg[\prod\limits_{i\in\Phi}\frac{\mu}{\mu+sR_i^{-\alpha}} \bigg]\\
&=\mathrm{exp}\bigg(-2\pi\lambda\displaystyle\int_r^{\infty} \bigg(1-\frac{\mu}{\mu+sv^{-\alpha}}\bigg)v\mathrm{d}v \bigg)
\end{align}$

where we can assume that $g_i\sim \mathrm{exp}(\mu)$, and plugging $s=\mu Tr^{\alpha}$ which gives

$\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}_{I_r}(\mu Tr^{\alpha})&=\mathrm{exp}\bigg(-2\pi\lambda\displaystyle\int_r^{\infty} \frac{T}{T+(v/r)^{\alpha}}v\mathrm{d}v \bigg)
\end{align}$

employing change of variables $u=\bigg(\frac{v}{rT^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}\bigg)^2$ results in

$\mathcal{L}_{I_r}(\mu Tr^{\alpha})=\mathrm{exp}(-\pi r^2 \lambda\rho(T,\alpha))$, where

$\rho(T,\alpha)=T^{2/\alpha}\displaystyle\int_{T^{-2/\alpha}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+u^{\alpha/2}}\mathrm{d}u$

If we rewrite

$\mathcal{L}_{I_r}(\mu Tr^{\alpha})=\exp\bigg(-2\pi\lambda\displaystyle\int_r^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+\bigg( \frac{v}{r}\bigg)^{\alpha}\frac{1}{T}} v\mathrm{d}v\bigg)$
with change of variables $u=\bigg(\frac{v}{rT^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}\bigg)^2$

we can get $u^{\alpha/2}=\bigg(\frac{v}{r}\bigg)^{\alpha}\frac{1}{T}$, then

$\mathcal{L}_{I_r}(\mu Tr^{\alpha})=\exp\bigg(-2\pi\lambda\displaystyle\int_r^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+u^{\alpha/2}} v\mathrm{d}v\bigg)$

write

$v=rT^{-1/\alpha}u^{1/2}$

$\mathrm{d}v=\frac{1}{2}rT^{-1/\alpha}u^{-1/\alpha}\mathrm{d}u$ then

$\mathcal{L}_{I_r}(\mu Tr^{\alpha})=\exp\bigg(-2\pi\lambda\displaystyle\int_r^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+u^{\alpha/2}} rT^{1/\alpha}u^{1/2}\frac{rT^{1/\alpha}}{2\sqrt{u}}\mathrm{d}u\bigg)$

$\mathcal{L}_{I_r}(\mu Tr^{\alpha})=\exp\bigg(-\pi\lambda r^2 T^{2/\alpha}\displaystyle\int_r^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+u^{\alpha/2}} \mathrm{d}u\bigg)$

How to change the integral limits from $\displaystyle\int_r^{\infty}$ to $\displaystyle\int_{T^{-2/\alpha}}^{\infty}$

Comment: This substitution allows to "pull" the parameters $r,T$ out of the integrand expression, making it easier to deal with. The integration bounds need to be adapted accordingly.

Comment: thank you for the comment, do you mean to pull the T out of integrand? and why we square it? sorry too many questions

Comment: Just compare the integrands before and after the transform, don't you see that the parameters are gone ?

Comment: thanks, i update it, but still can't figure out the changes for integral limits

Comment: Compare $v=r$ to $u=T^{-2/\alpha}$.

Comment: Ah i see, so basically if $u=\frac{v^2}{r^2 T^{-2/\alpha}}$ , where r = v, so $u=\frac{1}{T^{2/\alpha}}$ , thank you